# while use web Api for smtp mail getting error when try to attach files

Tags: jquery, asp.net-web-api

this is my code please help me.

```
[HttpGet]
public string sendmail( string email,string body, string attach)
{       

       MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
       SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
       mail.From = new MailAddress(email);
       mail.To.Add("sachinrameshgiri@gmail.com");
       mail.Subject = "Test Mail";
       System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment;
       attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(attach );
       mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);

       SmtpServer.Port = 587;
       SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("sachingiri.bca@gmail.com", "password");
       SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
       SmtpServer.Send(mail);

       return "success";
    }
```

and call it from HTML page using jquery ajax
 $(document).ready(function () {

```
        $("#btn1").click(function () {
            $.getJSON("api/person/sendmail", { email: "sachingiri.bca@gmail.com", body: "hi this is sachin giri !!!A software developer",attach:"  "}, function (data) ....
```

this is working for sending mail, but html input type="file" does not retuen path for upload, only return filename...so attachment is not working.